# JavaScript - Create an object from a variable containing a string?

Tags: javascript

If I am given properties as a string in multiple test cases...

```
var testCase = "Key1: 1, Key2: 2, key3: 3, key4: 4"
```

...is there a way in JavaScript to convert it to an object?

```
var myObj = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
    key4: 4
};
```

Comment: If it's not coming from user input, just use eval.

Comment: You can use a regex to parse the string `/(.+?): (.+?),?/g`

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate, but the accepted answer to that duplicate does not really apply, since it assumes that the keys are quotes.

Comment: @torazaburo: There is no accepted answer to that question but even if there was, the accepted answer isn't an "official" answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use the `eval` function as follows:

```
eval("var obj = {" + yourString + "}"); 
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: FWIW, This answered my question and parse did not work.